# Linear Regression with Caret

Tags: r, glm, caret

I could really use your help. I am trying to write an R script that takes some data and performs `glm` using the `caret` package. Here is my code:

```
set.seed(4000)
# Create training and test data with 80%-20% ratio
new_values$gender <- as.factor(new_values$gender)
trainingRows= createDataPartition(new_values$gender, p= .8, list= FALSE, times= 1)
training_data_set= new_values[trainingRows,]
test_data_set= new_values[-trainingRows,]
# Test training with 10 times cross-validation
fitness_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, savePredictions = TRUE)
# Train model with linear regression method (it takes about 5-10 minutes waiting time)
linear_regression <-train(gender~ ., data=training_data_set,method="glm",family=binomial(), trControl=fitness_control)
linear_regression
```

Here is the data table:
[new_data table](https://mega.nz/file/XIMDWYTY#0DC6o2S9Vf9jxYT0-VQdRwlHyT8RAsl11s1LryYk2hg)

When I try to run this script R takes really long time to load and after that I get this error message:

Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:

```
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1    
Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

The warning messages are:

Warning messages:
1: model fit failed for Fold01: parameter=none Error : protect(): protection stack overflow

2: model fit failed for Fold02: parameter=none Error : protect(): protection stack overflow

3: model fit failed for Fold03: parameter=none Error : protect(): protection stack overflow

4: model fit failed for Fold04: parameter=none Error : protect(): protection stack overflow

5: model fit failed for Fold05: parameter=none Error : protect(): protection stack overflow

6: model fit failed for Fold06: parameter=none Error : protect(): protection stack overflow

7: model fit failed for Fold07: parameter=none Error : protect(): protection stack overflow

8: model fit failed for Fold08: parameter=none Error : protect(): protection stack overflow

9: model fit failed for Fold09: parameter=none Error : protect(): protection stack overflow

10: model fit failed for Fold10: parameter=none Error : protect(): protection stack overflow

11: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  ... :
There were missing values in resampled performance measures.

Can you please help?

Comment: There is no column `gender` in that data, one first char column without header and 40 numeric columns.

Comment: @RuiBarradas sorry i had uploaded the wrong data, now it is fixed

Comment: What are the warnings?

Comment: Your problem is to have only 32 observations for 2464 predictors, try `fit<-glm(gender ~ ., data = training_data_set,family = binomial); summary(fit)` and see that 2432 coefficients are NA. Then accuracy, etc, will give NA.

Comment: @RuiBarradas ok so how can i fix this issue? Is the new_data table the problem? can i transform it somehow so i dont have this issue? sorry for the questions but i am to submit this task to the university by saturday

Comment: @bash1000 i added the warnings to the original post

Comment: I don't know about the warnings and errors, but if you really want to fit `n=32` (observations) with `p=2464` you're almost certainly going to need to use some kind of **penalized regression** (e.g. using `glmnet` for LASSO/ridge/elastic net regression). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72354337/how-do-i-use-the-means-of-the-columns-of-a-matrix-as-prediction-values-in-a-line/72354536#72354536) is related. (For what it's worth, you may get fairly terrible/non-generalizable answers anyway, with `n` this small and `p` this large ...)

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for the response...yes i understand that the method for this kind of dataset is ill advised but thats what the task assigned to me needs me to do...so all i have to do is replace the method from glm to glmnet?

Comment: UPDATE: i tried running the glmnet method and i had warning messages again

Answer (score 0):

Fitting with `glmnet` seems to work OK, although I haven't looked to see if the answers actually make sense! I had to sort out some data issues, which might have been what was getting in your way ...

```r
library(readxl)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(dplyr)
dd <- (read_excel("thema3_results1.xlsx")
    |> select(-1)  ## drop row names
    |> mutate(across(gender, factor))
    |> mutate(across(-gender, as.numeric))  ## convert character to numeric!
)

set.seed(4000)

trainingRows <- createDataPartition(dd$gender, p= .8, list= FALSE, times= 1)
training_data_set <-  dd[trainingRows,]
test_data_set <- dd[-trainingRows,]
# Test training with 10 times cross-validation
fitness_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, savePredictions = TRUE)
system.time(logistic_reg <- train(gender~ ., 
                          data=training_data_set,
                          method="glmnet",
                          family="binomial", ## not binomial() for glmnet ...
                          trControl=fitness_control))
```

The training step took about 2 seconds on my machine,

This seems to be getting accuracy == 1, which probably means it's still overfitting ... ???